# Foreground Service or standard service?

Tags: android, android-service

I have Fragment which is basically a View that shows any incoming messages for a user.  I want the create something that will check every 5 seconds for any new messages, and if found will append them to my ListView which holds the messages.  My question is, from what I have read, a Service is the way to go with this.  However, since I will be communicating with the app from this service I'd like to know which service I should use.

Should I be using a Foreground service, or just a standard Service?

My goal is that where ever the user is in my app, I will be able to receive some notification that a new message has come through and then perform a function when that happens.

I want to code this properly and according to best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to call a method on your service when user is in your app, you just need to use a **sticky** `service`, but if you want to call this method even when user swipe your app away from recent apps you should use **not_sticky** `service`.

**Foreground** `service` are most used for cases that u don't want your task stop even for a second after swiping your app from recent apps e.g. playing music in background.

**But in your case the best choice is to use `postDelayed()` and set 5 seconds delay for it** and get rid of `service`.